# Include OpenSSL in a CMakeList.txt file

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, openssl, podofo

I have a question for people who work with CMakeList.txt in C++. I want to use `Podofo` project (a project to parse & create pdf).

So my main function is simple as:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <podofo/podofo.h>

int main() {
  PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument pdf;
  pdf.Load("/Users/user/path/to.pdf");

  int nbOfPage = pdf.GetPageCount();

  std::cout << "Our pdf have " << nbOfPage << " pages." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My CMakeList.txt is:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But I am stuck with this error:

```
/usr/local/include/podofo/base/PdfEncrypt.h:44:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslconf.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h
```

I tried to include with `find_package`, `find_library` .. setting some variables but I do not find the way.

My env is:

- macOS
- Clion
- Podofo installed via home-brew in `/usr/local/podofo`
- OpenSSL installed via home-brew in `/usr/local/opt/openssl`

Thanks by advance community !!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`find_package` is the correct approach; you find details about it [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html).

In your case, you should add these lines:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(untitled OpenSSL::SSL)
```

If CMake doesn't find `OpenSSL` directly, you should set the CMake variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`.

Comment: Yeah that's it !!! 
Could you just explain me how did you found the syntax "OpenSSL:SSL", why not just "OpenSSL", I would never found that .

Now I have another error "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" but it's certainly a small mistakes

Comment: @nodeover did you look at the FindOpenSSL documentation that was given? These imported target names should always be in there or in the comments of the corresponding FindModule.cmake file. Also, if oLen solved this specific question for you, make sure to mark it as the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Oh so my second problem was because I missed "target_link_libraries(untitled podofo)" that line resolve the problem & I am able to build

Comment: @oLen Why not give `include_directores` or `target_include_directories` of openssl ?

Comment: @LewisChan It is not necessary, with this syntax `target_link_libraries` does it for you.