# How to link OpenSSL in CLion

Tags: c, openssl, clion

I'm currently working on a web server in `C` and I wanted to include  for hashing passwords. My problem right now is that I get the error `undefined reference to 'SHA1'` when trying to compile. It appears to be an error with the Linker because the building seemed to work fine.

This is how I call SHA1():

```
SHA1(src, srcLength, hashStr);
```

I've simply installed OpenSSL by using `apt-get install openssl`

Do I somehow have to add OpenSSL to the target_link_libraries in the CMake-File?

EDIT: Sorry, I miss-typed, I installed `openssl-dev`, not just `openssl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include OpenSSL in a CMakeList.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548088/include-openssl-in-a-cmakelist-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development package `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` which includes the necessary header files.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally typed openssl not openssl-dev here, I've already installed that

Comment: @Halsi well you also need  `find_package(OpenSSL)` and add `${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to your include dirs. And link the target library.